# Projective group of Plucker quadric over the reals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, quadratic-forms, grassmannians

A somewhat elementary question but seemingly difficult to find a suitable reference:

Consider the six-dimensional real space $\wedge^2(\mathbb R^4)$ with basis $e_i \wedge e_j \ (i < j)$ where $e_i, \ i = 1, \cdots, 4$ denotes the standard basis of $\mathbb R^4$ 
(Thus each vector $v \in  \wedge^2(\mathbb R^4)$ is given as
$v = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le 4} \xi_{ij}e_i \wedge e_j$).
The Plucker quadric is defined as the zero locus of the quadratic function $$ q(v): = \xi_{12}\xi_{34} 
- \xi_{13}\xi_{24} + \xi_{14}\xi_{23}. $$
With respect to the given basis the polarization of $q$ is given by the matrix
$$ P:= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 
& 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
Let $G$ be the isometry group of the quadratic form $q$, that is,
$$ G = \{ X \in GL(6, \mathbb R) \mid X^TPX = P \}. $$
Consider the Plucker quadric as a projective variety $\mathcal G$ in $\mathbf P(\wedge^2(\mathbb R^4))$. Let $\mathscr G$ be the group of projective transformations in $PGL(6, \mathbb R)$ that preserve
$\mathcal G$ as a set. Is it true that $\mathscr G = G/Z$ where
$Z$ denotes the center of $GL(6,\mathbb R)$. If not then what is $\mathscr G$? Will the answer change if $\mathbb R$ is throughout replaced by $\mathbb Q$.

What is (are) a suitable reference (s) for this topic?

Comment: In the case of an algebraically closed field such as $\bar {\mathbb Q}$ (where the main interest lies) this question has an affirmative answer as can be seen in M. Berger : Geometry II.